# sort objects in array with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to sort an array of dynamic key / values (Object) based on a property in the object. Can someone please provide me an example of how to do this. Ill try to create a similar structure to my issue

Order Class:

```
export class order {
  id: number; 
  productRank: number; 
  productId: number; 
  productName: string;
}
```

There is a storeOrders observable array of orders in my component

```
storeOrders$: Observable<Array<orders>>;
```

The key in the orders array is dynamically generated and is stored with the key/value containing  as key and order object as value

then the orders object for example is something like:

```
 let orders = {
12_123: { id: 123, productRank: 3, productId: 23, productName: 'shirt'},
23_124: { id: 124, productRank: 1, productId: 14, productName: 'cologne'},
67_124: { id: 125, productRank: 2, productId: 45, productName: 'belt' }       
 }
```

When i subscribe to this data, how can I iterate over the storeOrders array and sort items based on the productRank. I have been trying to get this right but was not able to get this working, can someone please point out how to iterate over dynamic keys in an array and do a sort based on a property in the value object? Thank you, your helps really appreciated!

Comment: your orders array is wrong. Simple you can't have key value pair in an array

Comment: @PratapA.K is right, are you sure `orders` isn't an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your orders should be a object as below,

```
orders = {
    12_123: { id: 123, productRank: 3, productId: 23, productName: 'shirt' },
    23_124: { id: 124, productRank: 1, productId: 14, productName: 'cologne' },
    67_124: { id: 125, productRank: 2, productId: 45, productName: 'belt' }
  };
```

you can form the values by using `Object.values(orders)`

I use `sortBy` from lodash library as I'm used to it and you get the sorted values as

```
console.log(sortBy(Object.values(orders),['productRank']));
```

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkxcv7)**

Comment: Using loadash is really not that useful here. Just `ordersValues = Object.values(orders); ordersValues.sort((o2, o1) => o2.productRank - o1.productRank);` should work out of the box.

Comment: @Jeto yes. I mentioned I'm used to `lodash` ! even array sort function should also work as you mentioned

Comment: @Aravind thanks for your help, I was struggling with this for a minute, esp iterating the dynamic keys was throwing me off

Answer (score 0):

to order a dynamic array of keys/values you can do this :

example of array :

```
arr = [
{de : 'germany'},
{fr : 'france'},
{uk : 'united kingdom'},
{tn : 'tunisia'}
]

arr.sort((a, b) => {

      const a_key = Object.keys(a);
      const a_value = a[a_key];
      const b_key = Object.keys(b);
      const b_value = b[b_key];

      if (a_value == b_value) return 0;
      return a_value > b_value ? 1 : -1;
    });
```

that's all !